# node ejs dynamic javascript load

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, p5.js

So i am trying to have the routes file pass a list of javascript files that need to be included for the page and have ejs construct the header to include these scripts

My routes file

```
router.get('/:name', function(req,res, next) {
  res.render('templates/experiment', {
    name:req.params.name,
    extraScripts:experiments[req.params.name].extraScripts
  })
});
```

my experiment.ejs

```
<head>
  <title><%= name %></title>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
  <% for(var i = 0; i < extraScripts.length; i++) { %>
    <script scr=<%= "../javascripts/" + extraScripts[i]%> ></script>
  <% }%>
  <script src=<%= "../javascripts/experiments/"+name + "/sketch.js"%>></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
```

now when i load the page i can see the script tag just fine but it is not doing the actual loading of the extra scripts.

```
<head>
  <title>snake</title>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>

  <script scr=../javascripts/library/colors.js ></script>

  <script src=../javascripts/experiments/snake/sketch.js></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
```

that colors.js file is not loading am I missing something, the sketch.js is dynamic and it loads just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code
Use *src* in place of *scr*.

Also try to enclose the src path inside double quotes as below

```
<head>
  <title><%= name %></title>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/p5/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
  <% for(var i = 0; i < extraScripts.length; i++) { %>
    <script src="<%= "../javascripts/" + extraScripts[i]%>" ></script>
  <% }%>
  <script src="<%= "../javascripts/experiments/"+name + "/sketch.js"%>"></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
```

Comment: wow normally when I type out questions like this i catch those stupid typos, thanks